# Jquery autocomplete only shows results after i type 4th letter on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a input where a user inserts a city name, and then i call a method with `onkeyup`

```
function autocompleteCity(id){


console.log($('#'+id).val());

if($('#'+id).val().length >= 2){
    var data = {
        query: $('#'+id).val()
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: location.origin + '/autocomplete/city',
        headers: {
            apiKey: APIKEY
        },
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {

            var cities = [];
            for(var i=0;i<data.cities.length;i++){
                cities.push(data.cities[i].city);
            }
            console.log(cities);

            $('#'+id).autocomplete({
                source: cities
            });

        },
        error: function (err) {

            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

}

and html

```
<input id="placeTo" onkeyup="autocompleteCity('placeTo')" type="text" class="form-control input-lg not-dark" value="" placeholder="Select a drop city">
```

For example if i type "To" i get this on `console.log(cities)`

```
Array [ "Toulouse", "Toronto", "Torun", "Tours" ]
```

but the autocomplete doesn't show, until the user types "Toky"

is this normal? or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: please share the html part

Comment: Have you used jquery ui autocomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your ajax you just need to implement the `source` option and for the minimum number of characters a user must type there is the `minLength` option.

```
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax( {
          url: location.origin + '/autocomplete/city',
          dataType: "json",
          type: "POST",
          headers: {
               apiKey: APIKEY
          },  
          data: {
            q: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {

            // Handle 'no match' indicated by [ "" ] response
            response( data.length === 1 && data[ 0 ].length === 0 ? [] : data );
          }
        } );
      },
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( "Selected: " + ui.item.label );
      }
}):
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a autocomplete with the minLength option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ minLength: 2 });
```

It will work